# C# How to delete certain rows from a CSV file and save it as a new CSV using CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm trying to delete certain rows from my CSV file but since I'm new to C# I can't figure out how to do it right.

I have this code that loads a CSV file and goes trough it.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"Data\myCSV.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Books>();
            var books = records.ToImmutableArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < books.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (books[i].title == "someTitle")
                {
                    //Delete this row
                }
            }
        //Overwrite old csv
        }
```

But I cannot find the code that would delete the indicated row.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think you _can_ delete something from an **immutable array**? Do you understand what the word _"immutable"_ means in this context? Why do you convert the data to an immutable array if you intend to remove a record from the data? Your question is unclear. It doesn't even really seem to have anything at all to do with CSV, never mind the CsvHelper library. Please improve it.

Answer (score 3):

You could pull all off the records into memory and then write them back to the file.

```cs
List<Books> records;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"Data\myCSV.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    records = csv.GetRecords<Books>().ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (records[i].Title == "someTitle")
        {
            records.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"Data\myCSV.csv"))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

For a larger file you might want to read one record at a time to memory and write it immediately back to a temporary file. Then delete the original file and rename the temporary file.

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"Data\myCSV.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"Data\myCSV_Temp.csv"))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    Books record;

    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();

    csvWriter.WriteHeader(typeof(Books));

    while (csv.Read())
    {
        record = csv.GetRecord<Books>();

        if (record.Title != "someTitle")
        {
            csvWriter.NextRecord();
            csvWriter.WriteRecord(record);
        }                    
    }                
}

File.Delete(@"Data\myCSV.csv");
File.Move(@"Data\myCSV_Temp.csv", @"Data\myCSV.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1397:

> CsvHelper is forward only, so you'll need to read through the existing file and write a new one.

Comment: I have come across that very post, but I don't know how to write a new file, or go through the existing one.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question to *that*, then. Are you familiar with CSVWriter? It's part of the same library, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

There are too many ways of doing this not specifically using CsvHelper, hence i'm listing few suggestions you can try

1. Simplest solution without getting into details, if the file is small enough(in MBs), read all lines into a List or IEnumerable and then you can do any operation on that collection and write the collection back to the file.
2. if you are new to c# try out all basic file operations before working on the actual project . Follow a tutorial such as https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_file_io.htm or videos on youtube
   Text Files : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cST5TT3OFyg
   File IO : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mUuJIKq40M

Use free tools like LinqPad or dotnetfiddle to try small code snippets before writing a large program.

3. once you are comfortable working with files using .Net libraries, you can look at using libraries such as https://www.filehelpers.net/ which make it very easy to work with files with a lot of configurable options. They also have a lot of turials on their website to work with files.